# iOS Update Label from Picker Each Time it Moves

Tags: ios, picker

I have a picker that shows the selected value in a text label.

I would like that label to get updated each time the picker value changes. At the moment if I change the value, press Done on the picker, then go to reselect only then it chose the value.

Any ideas how - i get the text from the picker using:

```
NSString *selectedItem =[_myArray objectAtIndex:[_myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

Comment: Have you implemented the UIPickerViewDelegate method `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the delegate method, pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:. This is called by the picker view when you select an item. Get the value from your array based on the row and component, and populate your label.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.label.text = _myArray[row];
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I'm actually new to iOS dev. Could you please give me a rough description of how it work??